# Ansible - Global Variables

Tags: jinja2, ansible

Is there someway to "global" variable in Ansible (that is to say across multiple hosts)? I want to set an error flag then call a specific separate playbook if we hit that error state. My structure is something like below:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - role1 <-- some error flag is set here
    - role2
- include: teardown.yml
  when: error_flag is defined and error_flag == true
```

I've tried setting a variable in `group_vars` but it appears to me there's also no real way to change variable values during run-time.

Set_fact doesn't work because the `when` for the teardown isn't in local host. And even if I try to access `hostvars['localhost']['error_flag]`, that doesn't work because it seems that you can't use Jinja templates in the `when` clause.

Comment: The host variable `hostvars.localhost.error_flag` should be accessible in a `when` clause without a Jinja2 template. That is, write that expression without the `{{` `}}` Jinja2 delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chin Huang said above, I was messing up the syntax regarding using the `when` clause. So by fixing that, the `when` clause obviously works.  There doesn't appear to be a good way to declare dynamic 'global' variables in Ansible, so using the variables per host in the `hostvars` object seems to be the most practical way.

Other sources have also mentioned using files and reading the data from files, but that seems incredibly inefficient. So I've been making due by saving things into `localhost`.